# ConstraintLayout: animating multiple views at once

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'd like to fade out a group of views in a ConstraintLayout. With a LinearLayout, I would wrap the views to fade out in a parent LinearLayout and animate the parent. Is that also the preferred approach for ConstraintLayout? It feels that that would defeat the purpose of a ConstraintLayout

Comment: Why not applying the same animation to all the target views and then start them togheter with `AnimatorSet.playTogether(...)`?

Comment: That seems heavy on the animation framework

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to take advantage of [ConstraintSets](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html).

You start with the original constraints on the views in the layout, create a second set of constraints, and then transition to the new constraints by "applying" them.

In this example, the second constraint set is derived from a nearly identical layout file. The only difference is that the ImageViews are set to visibility="invisible".

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    private ConstraintSet originalConstraints = new ConstraintSet();
    private ConstraintSet invisibleImageConstraints = new ConstraintSet();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        constraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        originalConstraints.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        invisibleImageConstraints.clone(this, R.layout.activity_main_invisible_images);
    }

    public void fadeOut(View v) {
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout);
        invisibleImageConstraints.applyTo(constraintLayout);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.albertcbraun.constraintlayouttest.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_view_1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.481"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="fadeOut"
        android:text="@string/fade_out"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_main_invisible_images.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_invisible_images"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.albertcbraun.constraintlayouttest.MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/image_view_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/image_view_1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.481"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:onClick="fadeOut"
        android:text="@string/fade_out"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```